# Where to put ruby helpers Sendgrid V3 Send API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am trying to integrate Sendgrid using their [Github documentation](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-ruby).

In their examples they suggest that you create a Mail Helper class but give very little guidance on how to actually do this.

I have a scheduled Rake task running using Heroku Scheduler that I would like to send an email when the task is complete and was hoping to use Sendgrid for this.

Currently I have the following code in `/lib/tasks/scheduler.rake`

```
require 'sendgrid-ruby'
include SendGrid

desc "Testing Email Rake"
task :test_sendgrid => :environment do
  puts 'Starting Sendgrid Email Test'
  send_task_complete_email()
  puts 'Sendgrid Email Test Complete'
end 

def send_task_complete_email
  from = Email.new(email: 'test@example.com')
  to = Email.new(email: 'test@example.com')
  subject = 'Sending with SendGrid is Fun'
  content = Content.new(type: 'text/plain', value: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Ruby')
  mail = Mail.new(from, subject, to, content)

  sg = SendGrid::API.new(api_key: ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY'])
  response = sg.client.mail._('send').post(request_body: mail.to_json)
  puts response.status_code
  puts response.body
  puts response.headers
end
```

I don't have the helper classes added anywhere as I am not sure which bits to add or where to put them. At the moment when I run this task I receive a `400 Bad request` error back from Sendgrid and I believe it's because I don't have these helpers in place.

Any advice to fix this would be much appreciated as when I try to integrate without using the helpers and instead writing out the JSON I can successfully send the email but receive a `TypeError: Mail is not a module` when I try to deploy to Heroku.

**UPDATE: ERROR RECEIVED USING ANSWER BELOW**

```
400
{"errors":[{"message":"Invalid type. Expected: object, given: string.","field":"(root)","help":"http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/errors.html#-Request-Body-Parameters"}]}
{"server"=>["nginx"], "date"=>["Thu, 07 Jun 2018 09:02:42 GMT"], "content-type"=>["application/json"], "content-length"=>["191"], "connection"=>["close"], "access-control-allow-origin"=>["https://sendgrid.api-docs.io"], "access-control-allow-methods"=>["POST"], "access-control-allow-headers"=>["Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl"], "access-control-max-age"=>["600"], "x-no-cors-reason"=>["https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html"]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [Action Mailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html):

First create a mailer class to add your mail details (i.e. UserMailer):

```
$ bin/rails generate mailer UserMailer
```

it will create the following files:

```
create  app/mailers/user_mailer.rb
create  app/mailers/application_mailer.rb
invoke  erb
create    app/views/user_mailer
create    app/views/layouts/mailer.text.erb
create    app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb
invoke  test_unit
create    test/mailers/user_mailer_test.rb
create    test/mailers/previews/user_mailer_preview.rb
```

Now edit the file `app/mailers/user_mailer.rb`:

```
require 'sendgrid-ruby'
include SendGrid

class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def send_task_complete_email
    from = Email.new(email: 'test@example.com')
    to = Email.new(email: 'test@example.com')
    subject = 'Sending with SendGrid is Fun'
    content = Content.new(type: 'text/plain', value: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Ruby')
    mail = Mail.new(from, subject, to, content)

    sg = SendGrid::API.new(api_key: ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY'])
    response = sg.client.mail._('send').post(request_body: mail.to_json)
    puts response.status_code
    puts response.body
    puts response.headers
  end
end
```

Then you can simply send emails using this code:

```
UserMailer.send_task_complete_email.deliver_now
```

Or from rake task:

```
desc "Testing Email Rake"
task :test_sendgrid => :environment do
  puts 'Starting Sendgrid Email Test'
  UserMailer.send_task_complete_email.deliver_now
  puts 'Sendgrid Email Test Complete'
end
```

**Update:**

Because there is `Mail` module in Rails, you need to specify the correct SendGrid Mail module by changing:

```
 mail = Mail.new(from, subject, to, content)
```

to

```
mail = SendGrid::Mail.new(from, subject, to, content)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately I am receiving a 400 error message when using this. My implementation is exactly as you have it an i've updated my question with the error i'm received. Thanks again for any help you can provide.

Comment: @TomPinchen can you please try to replace `mail = Mail.new(from, subject, to, content)` with `mail = SendGrid::Mail.new(from, subject, to, content)`

Comment: Amazing! This has worked, thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: Hurray for the update about the namespace conflict for `Mail`. That code is straight off their Ruby integration page, and also duplicated in the sendgrid-ruby documentation, and it _doesn't work_. So annoying.